# Formula of angle is equivalent to the geometric definition of cosine

Tags: trigonometry, vectors, triangles, angle

The angle between two vectors $\vec{v}$ and $\vec{w}\in \mathbb{R}^2$ of length $1$ is the number $\theta\in [0,2\pi)$, for which it holds that $\cos\theta=\langle \vec{v}\mid \vec{w}\rangle$.

Show using a right triangle why this is equivalent to the geometric definition of cosine (in the triangle).

Why do we need that the vectors have length $1$ ?

$$$$

From the triangle we get that $\cos\theta=\frac{\text{adjacent side}}{\text{hypotenuse}}$. How do we get from that the scalar product $\langle \vec{v}\mid \vec{w}\rangle$ ?

Comment: “The” number? For every $x \in [0,1]$, there are two values of $\theta\in[0,2\pi)$ for which $\cos\theta = x$.

Comment: Ah yes, you are right. I think I am able now to show that the geometric definition of the cosine id equivalent to the formula of the angle. Now the question thet remains is: "Why do we need that the vectors have length $1$ ? " Why is this necessary? @amd

Comment: Consider $\langle\vec v\mid\vec v\rangle$ when $\vec v$ isn’t a unit vector.

Comment: Then the hypotenuse of the triangle is not equal to $1$ and so we get that the formula is divided by this number, isn't it? Or is the justification something else? @amd

Comment: Could you give me a hint if I am thinking the right way or not? @amd